# Reinstalling Windows' MBR

Tags: windows, grub, mbr

I'd like to reinstall the Windows MBR.  My first hard drive is as follows:

```
(hd0,0): fedora 15/ext4
(hd0,1): windows 7 x64
```

I have GRUB installed on it right now, which allows me to boot Fedora just fine. However I'd like to reinstall the Windows MBR so I can boot Windows sometime in the future. I've booted from the install CD, selected *Command Prompt* and tried a few things like:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /nt60 all /mbr
fdisk # command not found
fixmbr # command not found
```

What should I do to fix this? I can burn Fedora/Ubuntu/Windows recovery discs as needed, but would like to fix this eventually.

Comment: You can setup GRUB to recognize and boot from Windows partition. Windows won't support Linux installations.

Comment: I know, but I thought you needed to install windows' mbr, then grub so it can point at windows' mbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is **truly** to reinstall the Windows MBR, using a WinPE cd, and running fdisk /mbr should do the trick. However, if your real goal is to be able to dual boot, then add the chainload information into your grub config. You don't need to re-install the Windows MBR to get grub to chainload.

As a case in point, when I build a dual boot system, I install windows first on what ends up being /dev/sda1. Then I install Linux on the rest of the drive (generally with /boot on /dev/sda2). As soon as grub installs during the linux install process, then the windows partition becomes unavailable. I finish by configuring the chain load in grub, and everything is golden.

To setup the chainloader, according to what you have in your question, you would need to add a section like this to your grub.conf (or menu.lst) in /boot:

```
title Windows
rootnoverify (hd0,1)
chainloader +1
```

This should work in grub. If you are using grub2, it would be different.

Comment: how can I get a windows pe disc?  The only one I found on ms' site was 900mb and requested I put in a key to be able to download it

Comment: There are lots of things out there that are alternatives. http://4sysops.com/archives/build-a-bootable-windows-pe-3-0-usb-drive-with-rescue-tools-part-1/ is one example. BartPE is another example.

Comment: I don't have a windows install that I can boot to.  Is there some iso I could use?

Comment: Another option might be to download a freedos CD or Thumbdrive image, and boot do that, since all you really need is fdisk. http://www.freedos.org/freedos/files/

Comment: got that, but `fdisk /mbr 1` (it's the first partition) leaves my computer unbootable, what should I do?  am I running the command wrong?

Comment: I'd just try fdisk /mbr

Comment: tried that; I got no output from the command, and when I tried to boot I got `partition signature != 55AA` (my first partition is the windows one)

Comment: As I recall, fdisk /mbr should not have any output at all. Silence is good. But since it isn't working, I am assuming that you can't boot into anything right now?

Comment: I couldn't, but I put the fedora 15 disc in and installed grub so I can boot fedora now (on /dev/sdb2), though it would be nice to boot windows later

Comment: Have you looked into setting up the chainload in grub?

Comment: grub points to that mbr already, however it doesn't boot.  I thought I needed an mbr and __then__ grub, right?

Comment: No, I don't think that is correct. Grub lives in your MBR. The MBR is just the first section of the disk, and grub inhabits it. Partitions don't have an MBR (but they may have boot sectors), only a full disk. So the way grub works is to take root in the MBR, and then hand off to kernels that are defined in it's config. Since it can't deal with the windows kernel, it just hands the boot process off to the specified partition. Since we know grub is working (Fedora boots, right?), then something else is amiss. Is there an error message when Windows fails to boot?

Comment: `invalid or unsupported execution format, press any key...`, I think that one's grub.  When I point it to the windows partition it says `BOOTMGR is missing, ctrl+alt+delete to restart`, I thought windows needed it's own mbr to boot?

Comment: Windows does have it's own bootmgr. What is weird is that I have never had to do anything special to make a dual boot work before, except for to configure grub appropriately. I'm not really sure how to proceed except to maybe start over with the system build from scratch.

Comment: yeah I've done that before, but I feel like I've had to do this once before (boot to windows tools to get a new mbr for windows).  I'll keep trying and try to let you know if I figure it out..

Comment: Here is what I would recommend. Partition the drive the way you want it, and install windows to the first partition. Install windows first. I'm very surprised that the Fedora installer is not detecting the Windows installer. I'm more of a debian / ubuntu guy myself, and it has been years since I've had to manually configure grub to detect my dual boot.

Comment: odd, I marked the windows partition as active, used bootrec with a few flags and the windows startup repair (don't know if that did anything this time), and it worked.  windows boots now

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to write a "Windows-like" MBR code.

Note that you can use grub to boot your Windows, using `chainloader`.

Comment: that seems like it should work.  however when I select the correct disk running testdisk for fedora 15 as root (/dev/sdb) and say 'write new mbr code' I still can't boot to it

Comment: Has the windows partition the `active` flag set?

Answer (score 0):

Start your computer with the **Windows CD** and choose repair. This will fix your Windows MBR and you will *lose* your Fedora GRUB. To fix that just follow these instructions:

> http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/

Comment: I did that, it said it couldn't find any problems and suggested I 'send a report' to microsoft