# problem with MBR having Windows 7-OpenSuse11.3 Dual boot

Tags: windows-7

My machine dual boots between Windows 7 and OpenSI have a configuration having windows 7 and openSUSE 11.3. However there is a problem with the version of openSUSE I have - it seems to be unstable - so I am intending to remove it.

On running the following command:

```
bcdedit /store C:\boot\bcd
```

I get:

```
Windows Boot Manager

identifier {bootmgr} .............................

Windows Boot Loader

identifier {default} .................................
```

A few more details suggest the bootloader is fine.

My MBR points to GRUB. Can I modify the MBR to point to my Windows bootloader?

Comment: Try Testdisk: http://superuser.com/questions/296730/reinstalling-windows-mbr/296759#296759

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's technically not an exact duplicate question, its answer is "Yes." and the further answer as to how is exactly the same as the answer to ["How to restore WindowXP loader within running Windows?"](https://superuser.com/questions/302021/).