# How to restore WindowXP loader within running Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, bootloader, mbr

How can i restore WindowXP loader after installation of boot manager(GRUB, LILO,..).

I can boot to windows, so it may be restored within windows enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to boot to the Recovery Console using your Windows install CD, then use [`fixboot`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixboot.mspx?mfr=true) and [`fixmbr`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) commands.

Newer Windows versions have a command [`bootsect`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(WS.10).aspx) ([download](http://ompldr.org/vOTgzOQ/bootsect.zip)), but it requires the drive to be unmounted. In other words, you cannot use it on the drive you booted from.