# One hard drive missing after converting from ide to ahci

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, ahci

I have two 500GB SATA HDD in my desktop running XP. After converting from IDE to AHCI, the HDD I use to store data can no longer be accessed from XP. It shows only the first partition as 150GB, and data type is listed as RAW. However, if I boot into a live linux environment or if I pull that HDD out and connect it using USB, I can still get to all my files again.

So I completely formatted the HDD into one single partition. But XP still does not recognize it. It still shows the disk as the 150GB partition and data type is still RAW. What's going on and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The master boot record needs to be cleared. Here are a few resources on how to do that:

- [Restore Windows XP MBR without Windows XP disc](https://superuser.com/questions/346433/restore-windows-xp-mbr-without-windows-xp-disc)
- [Reinstalling Windows' MBR](https://superuser.com/questions/296730/reinstalling-windows-mbr)
- [Fixing Disk Signature Collisions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2011/11/08/3463572.aspx)